# Button is on some devices visible and on some devices not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

A button in a tablecell is visible, when a check is true and not visible, when the check is false.

Here are the part of the function:

```
BOOL checked = [self checkObjekt:object];
if (checked == YES ) {
    [cell.buttonUpload setHidden:NO];
    [cell.buttonUpload setTitle:@"Geprüft, Upload!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonUpload setEnabled:YES];

} else {

    [cell.buttonUpload setHidden:YES];
    [cell.buttonUpload setTitle:@"Ungeprüft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonUpload setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I have proofed if the data from the object are correct. And in all databases are the value are true or yes, so the button should be visible. With the same database-file are only on some devices are the button not visible.

All Devices are on iOS 8.1.3 and they are iPad mini Retina.

Here is the full function:

```
- (void)configureCell:(MbsStartCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Objekt *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDate *rawDate = [object valueForKey:@"termin"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSString *strLabelUhrzeitbis;

if (nil != object.uhrzeitbis && ![object.uhrzeitbis isEqualToString:@""])
{
    strLabelUhrzeitbis = object.uhrzeitbis;
    cell.labelDatum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ zwischen %@ und %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:rawDate], object.uhrzeit, strLabelUhrzeitbis];
}
else
{
    cell.labelDatum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ um %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:rawDate], object.uhrzeit];
}

NSSet *adressen = object.adressen;
NSArray *adressenArray = [adressen allObjects];    

for (Adresse *adresse in adressenArray)
{
    if ([adresse.typ isEqualToString:@"Baustelle"])
    {
        if (adresse.anschrift1 && ![adresse.anschrift1 isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            cell.labelAnschrift.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adresse.anschrift2];

        } else {
            cell.labelAnschrift.text = adresse.anschrift2;
        }

        cell.labelStrassePlzOrt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", adresse.strasse, adresse.plz, adresse.ort];
    }
}

cell.labelObjektnummer.text = [[object valueForKey:@"objektnr"] description];
cell.labelFilale.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Filiale: %@, %@", object.filialname, object.objektanleger];
cell.labelAnrufer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Anrufer: %@", object.anrufer];

NSDate *rawSchadenstag = [object valueForKey:@"schadentag"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterSchadenstag = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterSchadenstag setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

cell.labelSchadentag.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Schadenstag: %@", [dateFormatterSchadenstag stringFromDate:rawSchadenstag]];

cell.labelSchadensursache.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Schadensursache: %@", object.schadensursache];
cell.labelSchadensursache.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.labelSchadensursache.numberOfLines = 2;

NSString *strWeitererHinweis;
if (nil != object.weitererhinweis)
{
    strWeitererHinweis = object.weitererhinweis;
}
else
{
    strWeitererHinweis = @"Es sind keine weiteren Hinweise vorhanden";
}

cell.labelWeitererHinweis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weiterer Hinweis: %@", strWeitererHinweis];
cell.labelWeitererHinweis.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.labelWeitererHinweis.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

int intTerminart = [object.terminart intValue];

switch (intTerminart) {
    case 1: {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.buttonUpload setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;            
    }
    case 2: {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [cell.buttonUpload setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;            
    }
    case 4: {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.buttonUpload setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    }
    case 5: {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        [cell.buttonUpload setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    }
    case 6: {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [cell.buttonUpload setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

BOOL checked = [self checkObjekt:object];
if (checked == YES ) {
    [cell.buttonUpload setHidden:NO];
    [cell.buttonUpload setTitle:@"Geprüft, Upload!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonUpload setEnabled:YES];

} else {

    [cell.buttonUpload setHidden:NO];
    [cell.buttonUpload setTitle:@"Ungeprüft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonUpload setEnabled:YES];
}
}
```

Here is the checkObjekt Function:

```
- (BOOL)checkObjekt:(Objekt *)objekt {

if ([[objekt.wohneinheiten allObjects] count] == 0) {
    return NO;
}

//Das Schadensformular für jede Wohneinheit wird in einer Schleife durchgearbeitet
for (Wohneinheit *wohneinheit in [objekt.wohneinheiten allObjects])
{
    MbsAppDelegate *delegate = (MbsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = nil;

    //Auswahl der richtigen Tabelle anhand der Terminart
    if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 1)
    {
        entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Schaden" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 2)
    {
        entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Leckortung" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 4)
    {
        entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aufbau" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 5)
    {
        entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Zwischenmessung" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 6)
    {
        entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Abbau" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wohneinheit == %@", wohneinheit];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (items == nil || [items count] != 1)
    {
        //Wenn kein Schadens- oder Leckortungsformular vorhanden ist, dann wird NO zurückgegeben
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        //Durchlaufen der einzelnen Checked Spalten.
        for (id item in items) {
            int tempChecked = 0;

            NSArray *checkedColumns = nil;
            if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 1)
            {
                checkedColumns = self.checkedColumnsTerminart1;
            }
            else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 2)
            {
                checkedColumns = self.checkedColumnsTerminart2;
            }
            else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 4)
            {
                checkedColumns = self.checkedColumnsTerminart4;
            }
            else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 5)
            {
                checkedColumns = self.checkedColumnsTerminart5;
            }
            else if ([objekt.terminart integerValue] == 6)
            {
                checkedColumns = self.checkedColumnsTerminart6;
            }

            for (NSString *checkedColumn in checkedColumns)
            {
                NSManagedObject *managedObject = (NSManagedObject *)item;

                NSDictionary * attributes = [[managedObject entity] attributesByName];

                NSArray *allKeys = [attributes allKeys];

                if ([allKeys containsObject:checkedColumn]) {
                    NSNumber *checkedColumnValue = (NSNumber *)[item valueForKey:checkedColumn];

                    if (checkedColumnValue != [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
                        tempChecked = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempChecked = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    tempChecked = 1;
                }
            }

            if(tempChecked == 0)
            {
                return NO;
            }
            else
            {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have included a lot of potentially irrelevant code. `checkObjekt` is obviously returning `NO`, but you haven't shown us that method.

Comment: I have added the method, but whey the checkObjekt should return no with exactly the same data on a device and on the other device it return yes.

Comment: Please show code for checkObjekt.

Comment: I added it to the text below

Comment: Now that we're sure it relies on your data set, you need to debug this yourself. Put breakpoints on each of the `return NO` lines in `checkObjekt` in order to determine which one is causing you the issue for you.

Comment: But can this happen, that the same data ( i use the same sqlite-files ) on different devices are return different data

Comment: On what devices is the button visible, and on which is it not?

Comment: Both are iPad mini Retina. Both have the same aktually iOS.